# xcode call/ get data from web service asmx

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, cocoa-touch

I want to get data from my web service in my app using Xcode 4
Any body has example about xcode - web service?

Comment: What kind of web service? REST, JSON-RPC, plain XML-RPC, SOAP, …? Cocoa has nice mid-level methods to make a request (`NSURLRequest` and friends), and to parse XML or JSON (`NSXMLDocument` or `NSJSON`), and so on. Apple's docs are full of samples, and if you google for "Cocoa web service tutorial" or "sample" you'll find dozens more. Or you can use the Web Services Core API, which is higher-level in that it ties it all together, but lower-level in that it's CoreFoundation rather than Foundation. Again, the docs have complete samples.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa comes with a framework called Web Services Core that was designed specifically for interacting with SOAP. And, as with most Apple technologies, the documentation that comes with Xcode (and is available on developer.apple.com) has a document called [Web Services Core Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/UsingWebservices/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's got a nice introduction, lots of sample code, and links to the appropriate references.

If you'd prefer to use NSURLConnection and NSXMLDocument instead of Web Services Core (they're at a lower level in terms of how much logic you have to write, but a higher level in terms of being ObjC objects that automatically participate in ARC, etc.), there are similar guides and references in Apple's documentation. There's no documentation on how to put them together into a complete Web Services client, but if you know how web services work, you should be able to figure it out. If not, a quick google on the two terms together shows samples like [A Cocoa application driven by HTTP data](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html) that make it obvious. The only part left is doing the SOAPiness on top of the basic XML, but that's the easy part.

If you google on Cocoa and SOAP together, the top two results, [Interacting with SOAP based web services from Cocoa, part 1](http://macresearch.org/interacting-soap-based-web-services-cocoa-part-1) and an open source Cocoa app called [SOAP Client](http://ditchnet.org/soapclient/), both of them seem informative and useful to get you started.

Meanwhile, there's nothing forcing you to use Apple's classes at all; there are plenty of C (and a few C++, if you don't mind ObjC++) open source libraries out there that you can pick up and wrap in ObjC yourself at whatever level you find appropriate.

Or… Is there a reason this has to be in ObjC? The Applescript bindings to Web Services are much simpler than the ObjC ones; Python and Ruby both come with simpler tools in their standard library than the Cocoa ones; etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to use the SOAP services than my advice is don't.....because for SOAP services you may able to construct the base classes using http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/
but the response you will get from the service will give the references and the whole data structures along with response and you can't parse the response.

Answer (score -1):

upload your web service link on this website and it will generate the needed classes for you to use with your WS
www.sudzc.com